# express router not resolving path correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working on an application. In that application I defined all my routes in config file and I created a middleware to load all routes.

Below is middleware code

```
var loadRoutes = function(router, config, controllers) {
  var route, routeValues, routeKeys, verb,
    path, controllerName, actionName, actionMethod;

  //load and initialize secured routes
  for (route in config.routes.secured) {
    if (config.routes.secured.hasOwnProperty(route)) {
      routeValues = config.routes.secured[route].split('#');
      if (routeValues.length !== 2) {
        throw new Error('ERROR Route value "' + config.routes.secured[route] + 
          '" Route value must be "<controller-name>#<action-method-name>",' + ' like "foo#index"');
      }

      routeKeys = route.split(' ');
      if (routeKeys.length !== 2) {
        throw new Error('ERROR Route key "' + route + '" Route key must be "<HTTP-verb> <path-pattern>", like "GET /foo/:id"');
      }

      verb = routeKeys[0];
      path = routeKeys[1];
      controllerName = routeValues[0];
      actionName = routeValues[1];
      if (!routingMethods[verb]) {
        throw new Error('HTTP verb "' + verb + '" for route "' + route + '" is not supported!');
      }

      if (!controllers[controllerName]) {
        throw new Error('Controller "' + controllerName + '" is not available for route "' + route + '"!');
      }

      actionMethod = controllers[controllerName][actionName];
        if (!actionMethod) {
          throw new Error('Action method "' + controllerName + '#' + actionName + '" is not available for route "' + route + '"!');
      }
      console.log(routingMethods[verb]);
      console.log(path);
      router[routingMethods[verb]](path, auth(), controllers[controllerName][actionName]);
    }
  }
};
```

The router is an instance of `express.Router();`

I defined the routes configuration as

```
{
  "routes": {
    "secured": {
      "GET /users/me": "UserController#getMyUserProfile",
      "PUT /users/me": "UserController#updateCurrentUserProfile",
      "POST /forgotPassword": "UserController#recoverPassword",
      "POST /resetPassword": "UserController#resetPassword",
      "GET /users/:id": "UserController#getUserProfile",
    }
  }
}
```

Now when I send request for `/users/me` the request is going to `/users/:id` controller method. Why it is happening?

I defined `/users/me` route before `/users/:id`

EDIT:
Adding routingMethods variable

```
var routingMethods = {
  GET: 'get',
  POST: 'post',
  PUT: 'put',
  DELETE: 'delete',
  HEAD: 'head',
  OPTIONS: 'options'
};
```

Comment: What does `routingMethods` look like?

Comment: `/users/:id` is conflicting with it.  `:id` is anything you put after `/users/` and even tho properties don't necessarily go in order, yours are probably just unlucky and it's being defined last so it overrides the others with `/users/me`

Comment: replace the `GET /users/me...` and the `GET /users/:id...` with one single handler that just does a check on what the param value is

Comment: Using single route fixed the issue. But I have used this in the past with multiple routes and it was working. I don't know why it is broken now. Will check on this later. Thanks

Comment: What version of Express are you using?

Comment: @mscdex I am using express 4.9.7